# VPN Like Internet Sharing (Securely)

Tags: network-shares

Here is the thing, in my country that is IRAN there are lot's of censorship on net. Lot's of websites are filtered and cannot be opened. So I purchased a Dedicated server in USA in order to give the opportunity to some of my colleagues and friend to use uncensored internet.

You cannot just setup a transparent proxy server on the server in order to share the internet. Since it is transparent IRAN isps can see and block unauthorized requests. One solution is setting up ssh on the server and by using putty on the client redirect all the request to a secure channel on the server, this method is very hard to setup.

So I couldn't find an easy solution for this purpose. I want to give each user a username and password (may be bandwidth limit for each one if it's possible) and also I want to permit only 1 user to login with a username ( so if one is logged in another one can't )

My guess is, it has to be some sort of vpn but as you all aware of, PPTPs for example has some compatibility issues.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: the method has to be very easy since lot's of my friends have a very little knowledge about networks and internet... they just can use a username and password (and may be an application) in order to setup things not more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want to share the regular Internet or some private resources?
And do you need only HTTP or everything (Skype, BitTorrent, etc)?

For the regular Internet (especially if you only need HTTP), you should be able to use existing proxy solutions, such as [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/).

For a more complete solution VPN is probably the easiest to set-up, there are good clients for all operating systems.

Comment: Regular internet sharing is my will.
Tor has it's own network, by tor you cannot share your internet (tell me if i'm wrong). And by VPN to what type of VPN you are referring to?

Comment: In addition to Tor-internal (anonymously hosted) sites, Tor can also be used as a proxy to the regular Internet.